# Why getting unexpected nil value passing data already loaded in tableview by a segue

Tags: ios, swift, popup, tableview, segue

well my problem is that idk how to pass the info values from the uitableviewcell to the anotherviewcontroller by the segue, could you please help, im unwraped the value, cause the data is already loaded idk what to do to pass the info to the popup controller without crashed

Here is my class model where i set the values

```
class MovieCell: UITableViewCell {
    //
    // MARK: - Class Constants
    //
    static let identifier = "MovieCell"
    let urlImage = "https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500"
    //
    // MARK: - IBOutlets
    //
    @IBOutlet weak var title: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var rating: RatingView!
    @IBOutlet weak var releaseDate: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var poster: UIImageView!
    var titlePopUp: String = ""
    func configure(movieDictionary: [String: Any]) {

        title.text = (movieDictionary["title"] as! String)
        titlePopUp = movieDictionary["title"] as! String
       
        releaseDate.text = (movieDictionary["release_date"] as! String)
        do {
            let url = URL(string: "\(self.urlImage)" + "\(movieDictionary["backdrop_path"]!)")
            let data = try Data(contentsOf: url!)
            self.poster!.image = UIImage(data: data)
                
        }
        catch{
            print(error)
        }
    }
}
```

heres is the viewcontroller where i get the error in the line 53

```
class ViewController: UIViewController,UITableViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
    
    var jsonArray: [Any] = []
    let movieService = MovieService()
    let popUpVC  = popUpViewController()
    @IBOutlet weak var moviesTableView: UITableView!
    @IBOutlet weak var postersView: UICollectionView!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        movieService.fetchMovies { jsonArray in
            if let jsonArray = jsonArray {
                self.jsonArray = jsonArray
                self.moviesTableView.reloadData()
                self.postersView.reloadData()
            }
        }
        self.moviesTableView.delegate = self
        self.moviesTableView.dataSource = self
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        self.jsonArray.count
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell:MovieCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "MovieCell", for: indexPath) as! MovieCell
        cell.configure(movieDictionary: jsonArray[indexPath.row] as! [String: Any])
        return cell
    }
   
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
       present(popUpVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
       moviesTableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
        
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "popUp", sender: self)
        
    }
    
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "popUp" {
            let destinationVC = segue.destination as! popUpViewController
            let data = MovieCell()
            destinationVC.movieN = data.title.text!
        }
    }
}
```

and the popup controller is this one

```
class popUpViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var poster: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var movieName: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var releaseDate: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var descriptionMovie: UILabel!
    
    var movieN = String()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        movieName.text = movieN
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }
    
    @IBAction func closePop(_ sender: UIButton) {
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

im getting crash passing the label and image, the clasical error, unexpected nil value, but idk why the data is already loaded in the tableview main screen

Comment: Please don't add images of code. [edit] your question to include code as text. It makes it easier to read, easier for people to test and easier to copy into an answer. Also, provide more information on which line is throwing the exception.

Comment: What you want to do here, i don't thing you want to create new cell and send to destinationVC ?

Comment: i want to send the info loading on my viewcell pass to the popup viewcontroller and display it there, but i try to do it it shows the error.

Answer (score 0):

You're not getting the data from the cell is because in the `prepare` method, you're creating a **new** instance of the cell.

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "popUp" {
        let destinationVC = segue.destination as! popUpViewController
        let data = MovieCell() // This is where the issue is
        destinationVC.movieN = data.title.text!
    }
}
```

The newly created cell instance has no relationship with the one that's already displaying the data. In the new cell, all the properties are either empty or `nil`. That's why you're getting the 'unexpected nil value' error.

To get that cell's values, you should get a *reference* to that cell.

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    guard let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as? MovieCell else { return }
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "popUp", sender: cell.titlePopUp)
}
```

Here you get the cell the user taps on and casts it to the `MovieCell` to access its `titlePopUp` property.

The you pass it to the `prepare` method in the `sender` parameter.

Finally in the `prepare` method, you cast it back to `String` (because the `sender` parameter is of type `Any`) and pass it to the popup view.

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "popUp" {
        let destinationVC = segue.destination as! popUpViewController
        destinationVC.movieN = sender as? String
    }
}
```

---

A few final notes: This way of passing around JSON as dictionaries will get the job done but will cause you massive headaches for you down the line if you have to change/maintain your code. What if later you have to pass another value of a movie along with the title to the popup? It's going to become harder and harder to scale this.

Do look in to object oriented way of programming. For example, create a class/struct called `Movie` to hold all the data (title, release date, rating etc). In the movie service, parse your JSON and create instances of that object and pass them up to the view controller.

Comment: i used sender and it crashed, idk how to instance the value from the moviecell i just cant do it, as you said is a problem

Comment: @ZacMazk In the `didSelectRowAt`, after you get a reference to the cell with `cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as? MovieCell`, do a print to (`print(cell.titlePopUp)`) and see if you're getting the value of the `titlePopUp`.

Comment: I already resolver the problem, i was using as sender: self instead of sender: cell

Comment: let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! MovieCell
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "popUp", sender: cell)

Answer (score 0):

i already solved sender was: cell not self

```
 let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! MovieCell
 self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "popUp", sender: cell)
```

and the data passed in the segue

```
  if segue.identifier == "popUp" {
        if let cell = sender as? MovieCell{
            let destinationVC = segue.destination as! popUpViewController
            destinationVC.movieN = cell.title.text!
            let url = cell.urlImage + cell.posterPath
            destinationVC.posterUrl = url
            destinationVC.descriptionText = cell.descriptionMovie
            destinationVC.releaseDateText = cell.releaseDate.text!
        }
    }
```